# String Error? Error: invalid syntax (<string>, line 9)

Tags: python

I'm getting the following error:  invalid syntax (, line 9)

Trying to work my way through the book "learn Python 3 the hard way" but I can't seem to find the error in the statement...

```
my_name = 'Zed A. Shaw'
my_age = 35 # not a lie
my_height = 74 # inches
my_weight = 180 # lbs
my_eyes = 'Blue'
my_teeth = 'White'
my_hair = 'Brown'

print(f"Lets talk about {my_name}.")
print(f"He's{my_height}inches tall.")
print(f"He's{my_weight}pounds heavy.")
print("Actually that's not too heavy")
print(f"He's got {my_eyes}eyes and {my_hair}hair.")
print(f"His teeth are usually{my_teeth} depending on the coffee")

# this line is tricky, try to get it exactly right
total= my_age + my_height + my_weight
print(f"If I add {my_age},{my_height}, and {my_weight} I get {total}.")
```

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? `f`-string syntax is [relatively new](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). Also note https://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints.

Comment: It could be an issue with your compiler. It is working [here](http://tpcg.io/OJkOCN)

Comment: I’ll check my version.  Hadn’t thought about that